# Simplifying javascript with variables

Tags: javascript, variables, simplify

```
if (this.firstChild.style.display == 'none')
{this.firstChild.style.display = 'block'}
else
{this.firstChild.style.display = 'none'};
```

Is it possible to shorten this code using variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can shorten it like this:

```
var a = this.firstChild.style;
a.display = (a.display=='none'?'block':'none');
```

Comment: That will assign the string 'block' to the variable `a`, and not to the property `display` of the element

Answer (score 2):

```
var childStyle=this.firstChild.style;
if ( childStyle.display == 'none'){
    childStyle.display = 'block';
}
else{
    childStyle.display = 'none';
}
```

will be the equivalent.

You can shorten in further using **ternary operator** like

```
var childStyle=this.firstChild.style;
childStyle.display=(childStyle.display=='none')?'block':'none';
```

Comment: That will assign the string 'block' to the variable `childStyle`, and not to the property `display` of the element

Comment: Oh , i didn't intend to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for jquery than its shorten than this

```
$("div span:first-child").toggle();
```

or

```
$(this).find(">:first-child").toggle();
```

Comment: That will add a >60KB javascript file. :D .

Comment: jQuery is nearly always the way to go.

Comment: Simplest way to do is the ternary operation. But for readability and easiness, yes , jQuery is better.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - toggle function do samething check : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Yeah yeah, Pranay Rana, I already agreed that your answer is the best for sure. Just trying to think alternative ways :)

Answer (score 1):

By the way, can this be another alternative?

```
with this.firstChild.style.display{this=(this=='none')?'block':'none';}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use _with_

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var elstyle = this.firstChild.style;
elstyle.display = /block/i.test(elstyle.display) ? 'none' : 'block'
```

Comment: Oh no. You made it complex. :D

Comment: What's complex about it? The OP asked: *Is it possible to shorten this code using variables*. This is an answer.

Comment: At least swap the ternary and test positive